# Manual athentication fails in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to make a custom login but Auth::attempt returns false.

This my controller:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MyUserController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        }
    }

}
```

This is auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'usuarios',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'usuarios',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'usuarios' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => Usuario::class,
    ],
```

The error I'm getting is

Class '\Usuario' not found {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class '\Usuario' not found at /var/www/laravel-boilerplate/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php:183)

Comment: Fix `Usuario::class`. Add full namespace to it. Like `App\Models\Usuario::class` or `App\Usuario::class`

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing password. Specify the field names

```
$credentials = $request->only('mail', 'password_laravel');

if (Auth::attempt(['mail'=>$credentials->mail, 'password'=>$credentials->password])) {
    
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect()->intended('/');

} else {
    Log::info('Authentication failed.');
}
```

**Notice**: Regenerate the session after `attempt` function. As said [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users).

Comment: Thank you so much. I was misplacing my database fields. Now the error I'm getting is: ERROR: Class '\Usuario' not found {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class '\\Usuario' not found at /var/www/laravel-boilerplate/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php:183).

Comment: You're welcome. Please post your `config/auth.php` file here. The `providers` section.

Comment: Fix `Usuario::class`. Add full namespace to it. Like `App\Models\Usuario::class` or `App\Usuario::class`